# Expand variadic arguments in initializer list fails

Tags: c++, asynchronous, lambda, variadic-templates

I try to create  a simple program in which I want to create vector of future arguments.
I created a wrapper function which is used to submit lambda functions and stores internally in a vector the future objects

I use an intermediate step in which I create an initiliazer_list using variadic arguments . But fails to compile. I try to use to call a function in order to push the elements in the vector and fails to compile as well

Below  is the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <functional>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <chrono>
#include <initializer_list>
using namespace std;
using FunctPtr  = function<int(int, int) >;
using FutureInt = future<int>;
using AsyncVector = vector<FutureInt>;
AsyncVector asyncVec;

template<typename... TemplatePtr>
void submit(TemplatePtr... pFunc)
{
  auto initList {pFunc... };
  for (auto & element : initList)
  {
      asyncVec.emplace_back(async(launch::async, element,4,5));
  }
}


int main()
{
    int a;
    int b;
    auto addPtr = [](int x, int y)->int 
    {
        std::cout << "add :" << x + y << std::endl;
        return x + y; 
    };
    auto multPtr = [](int x, int y)->int
    {
        std::cout << "mult :" << x * y << std::endl;
        return x * y;
    };
   // submit(add,4,5);
    submit(addPtr, multPtr);
    for (auto & v : asyncVec)
    {
        std::cout << "Wait for " << v.get() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are of different types so cannot be in the same init-list easily.

Your best options should probably be:

1. Either push them all into `asyncVec` in the same fold-expression.

```cpp
template<typename... TemplatePtr>
void submit(TemplatePtr... pFunc)
{
  (asyncVec.emplace_back(async(launch::async, std::move(pFunc), 4, 5)), ...);
}
```

2. Or, if they all are of the same signature, type-erase them, like keeping them in an array of `std::function`.

```cpp
template<typename... TemplatePtr>
void submit(TemplatePtr... pFunc)
{
  for (auto &&element: {std::function<int(int, int)>(std::move(pFunc))...})
  {
      asyncVec.emplace_back(async(launch::async, std::move(element), 4, 5));
  }
}
```

(I have specified function signature explicitly though compiler should be able to deduce it.)

3. Or, if all closures are captureless and of the same signature, simply cast them to the same type when calling `submit`:

```cpp
using SameType = int (*)(int, int);
submit(static_cast<SameType>(addPtr), static_cast<SameType>(mulPtr));
```

This way your original `submit` should work as is.